# 504 Gateway time-out when conducting a SQLite SELECT and then an UPDATE in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I have installed Raspbian Stretch on a Raspberry Pi including PHP 7 and SQLite 3.

I have numerous pages merrily working to SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE database values in different ways. However I struck a problem on one particular PHP page when I went to SELECT some data from a table and then UPDATE it straight afterwards.

To demonstrate the problem, from the command line I created a table called `testdb` in a database called `monitoring`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testdb ('name' TEXT NOT NULL, 'color' TEXT, 'schedule' INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

I then added a row with some random values;

```
INSERT INTO testdb (name, color, schedule) VALUES ("testing","green",2);
```

My example PHP code that results in the 504 Gateway Time-out is as follows

```
<?php

// select a row in testdb
$db = new PDO('sqlite:/srv/monitoring/monitoring');
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT color FROM testdb WHERE name='testing';");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
$db = null;
echo $result['color'];


// Update testdb
$db = new PDO('sqlite:/srv/monitoring/monitoring');
$sql =  "UPDATE testdb SET color = 'green', schedule = 2 WHERE name = 'testing'";
$stmt = $db -> prepare($sql);
$stmt -> execute();
$db = null;

?>
```

I can run either the SELECT block or the UPDATE block by themselves and they will work (which I can confirm by checking the table from the command line, and hence there are no permissions or access problems with the database). But if I try to load the page as I would a normal page I get a time-out.

In the production code I have variables that I'm using dynamically, hence the PDO usage (good practice right). But even with fixed values I'm struggling.

I suspect it's something simple and foolish that I've messed up, but I'm darned if I see it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't have an answer for the problem, but the code now works the following day. I can only presume that the problem was related to something that was occurring at the time. I assume that it wasn't browser based because while the timeout was occurring other pages couldn't access the database. The Raspberry Pi wasn't updated or rebooted. I'm at a loss.

I did think overnight that I would simply combine the code into one sequence that would select and then update without treating each block as a standalone unit, but since it worked I have retained the original form. Weird.